# Angle in 360 degrees

Tags: java, math, geometry, angle

I coded this code here:

```
     double cosine = (v1.x*v2.x+v1.y*v2.y)/(150*150);               
     double radian = Math.acos(cosine);
     double angle = Math.toDegrees(radian);
```

V1 and V2 are two vectors, which are simple Point(s)() to keep it simple. Now I calc. the angle between them and it works well. But over 180 deg. , it turns back to 179,178... But I want to have 360°.

The Problem is that for example radian won't get negative, so that I'm able to put it in an if-Segment...

Thanks for advice.

Comment: This seems more of a math problem than a coding problem.  How would you do this with paper and pencil?

Comment: yes, i think it's a math problem, too. The way I coded it is the way I would do it on paper(I learned it that way). It seems that the beginning line just give me the smaller angle.

Comment: acos always return a value for the first two quadrants. You will have to decide the quadrant you are in from your vertices and then adapt your result accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get full-range angle (-Pi..Pi for the most of math libraries) using both scalar product and cross product:

```
radian = Math.atan2(v1.x*v2.y-v1.y*v2.x, v1.x*v2.x+v1.y*v2.y)
```

Comment: Ah I see. okay, but I still have to check if it's <0 or something like that?

Comment: mh, well i changed it and there are values from 0<->180 and 0<->-179

Comment: I solved it with:
 double diff = 180+Math.toDegrees(radian);
      
      if(radian<0){       
        angle = 180+diff;
      }

Comment: It would better to add 360 once (if negative) -  to get angle needed to turn v1 counterclockwise until v2

Answer (score 2):

You're using the dot product of the two vectors to calculate the angle between them, but, since the dot product is commutative `a.b = b.a` - therefore, there is no way to get the sense of the angle, only its magnitude (as you've found out) - `acos` is ambiguous over 180º.

Try instead using `atan2`. It should be something like :

```
double theta1 = Math.atan2(v1.y, v1.x);
double theta2 = Math.atan2(v2.y, v2.x);
double theta = theta1 - theta2;
```

Note that `atan2` always returns an answer in -pi ... pi, so you will have to add pi to make it in the range 0 ... 2.0 * pi.

Comment: You don't want to add pi.  You want to add 2*pi if it's less than 0.